# Can I expose ports in .drone.file? drone.io

Tags: drone.io

I use Drone as CI tool. I have drone sever and drone agent which are docker containers. I connected Drone to my GitHub repository. And it works perfectly it responds for each pull and build docker container. I can see built container in output of command:

```
docker ps
```

In this container I have node server. It listens 3001 port. I want to expose this port. I want to do something like:

```
ports:
  - 3001:3001
```

in docker-compose.yml file.

Is it possible to expose ports in .drone.yml file? If it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use expose on Drone, because each test should be isolated to outer environment.

Are you about to run E2E test for web server build on node server?
If so, **service** section is available. http://docs.drone.io/services/